# Modify included layout in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using an include tag in an Android layout file to include a relative layout row that I would like to repeat a few times. The problem is that after I include the row I cannot modify the text of a textview inside the layout. Is there anyway I can modify the text of a textview that is part of an include? Mainly I would like to insert 4 of these rows with custom text specified in the xml if possible.

Comment: Only from runtime, you cannot do it statically on xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it only at runtime. Even if you do it at runtime, make sure you call findViewById from the parent view as Android doesn't allow you to use the same ID at more than one place in an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add these 4 includes with a different id and get them from code or do what @Anis said and inflate them at runtime and put there your text.