# Modify View in a layout included in another layout using <include> tag

Tags: android, layout, include, runtime

I have a layout as :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I have included it in another layout as :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I modify the attributes of ImageView in the included layout.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917110/modify-included-layout-in-android). The answers say it can only be done at run time, but don't explain how to get the reference of ImageView from included layout programatically.

Please explain how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your view:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And from your activity:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```

Comment: I need to access ImageView in my Activity from the included layout, not the main layout containing it.

Comment: It should work like this: myImageView will reference the ImageView from the included layout. Then the activity can modify its attributes like myImageView.visibility = View.HIDDEN or whatever. Did you test it? What happened?